# Assign a unique id sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table that has the following records:

```
PatientId    PersonIdentifier
1            abc
2            abc
3            def
4            def
5            def
```

I want to assign a personId that is numeric. So person identifier abc will both have Id 1 and def will all have Id 2. How do I do this?

I've tried row num, rank etc, but can't seem to get it to work.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

[`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would seem the correct option here.

```
select PatientId, PersonIdentifier,
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY PersonIdentifier) as Id
from SomeUnknownTable
```

You want *ranking* because you want to assign multiple rows the *same* values (and this isn't a `PARTITION`ing situation). And you want dense ranking so that multiple rows assigned the same value don't "consume" additional values behind the scenes.